# Retrofit2 send Bearer Token

Tags: android, retrofit2

I've tried sending the token with a HeaderMap but get a 401 code response. The way my project is setup is that I have a separate file for my `ApiClient` and I have a `OkHttpClient Interceptor` and a `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to see whats going on, however I can't get the Bearer Token to work. I've seen solutions that add it to the interceptor as a header in the interceptor and I've tried this but since my token is saved in SharedPreferences I can't get it to work in the ApiClient class I have.

This is the ApiClient

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setLenient().create();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @NotNull
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                //I would add the header here
                //I tried this but it says on "ApiClient.this" cannot be referenced from static context
                // .header("Authorization" , SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserToken(ApiClient.this));
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        })
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .build();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.6:8000/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

This is the method from `SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserToken(MainActivity.this)`

```
public static String getUserToken(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
    return sp.getString(USER_TOKEN, null);
}
```

This is the current call where the response is 401, If I don't add the Accept => application/json the response url is incorrect and also returns a html page when I need a simple response `return response("LoggedOut", 200); //this is the response in the api`

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
headers.put("Token", SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserToken(MainActivity.this));

Call<Void> call = apiInterface.LogoutUser(headers);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
    // onResponse and onFailure here
}
```

For example without the Accept header this is the response in the Logcat

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.0.6:8000/api/logout
D/OkHttp: Token: wE1Y8IxJpwyXtvw0fYoXZAlQ6qCx24YtzonQIeJBQSHmNppe0Sn1kLYDgZKCw4MKbpab4Vspf61Nzer1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.0.6:8000/login
//a bunch of html that's the web page at this route, notice the /api is missing
```

How can I send this correctly?

EDIT: 
I"m using a Laravel project for the backend and this is the relevant route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->get('/logoutApi', function (Request $request) {

    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();

    return response("LoggedOut", 202);
});
```

Comment: Can you share your backend server code for this endpoint?

Comment: I added it @mubin986

Answer (score 0):

create class Authenticator, like:

```
const val HEADER_TOKEN_FIELD = "Authorization"
class ClassAuthenticator(
    private val pref: SharedPref
) : Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

        return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header(HEADER_TOKEN_FIELD, pref.getToken())
                .build()
    }
}
```

then add interceptor in your client with:

```
 val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .authenticator(ClassAuthenticator(pref))
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val httpRequest = request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(HEADER_TOKEN_FIELD, 
                          "Bearer ${pref.getToken()}")
                        .build()
                val response = chain.proceed(httpRequest)
                response
            }
            .build()
```

Comment: I"m sorry where would I put this ?

Comment: if you already have the authenticator, you can add on 

`OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().authenticator(authenticator).
...
`

Comment: I did a work around where I add the token as a parameter for creating the ApiClient and send the token through like that

Comment: what about the accept header and the 401 code? any ideas?

Comment: Authenticator is used when you request returns 401 and you need to update your token. u can set your token on interceptor like the code. edited my answer

Comment: sory im using kotlin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211154/discussion-between-nancy-and-ade-dyas).